# How to integrate our web application with Cobas IT 3000 using sockets?

Tags: java

Our web application uses JSF framework. We need to do lab integration with Roches' Cobas IT 3000. How to connect with Cobas using only its ip address? Cobas technical person said that they didnt define any port number.

Comment: don't they have http api ?

Comment: Actually our web application need to order lab request by sending hl7 message to Cobas. They will process and send the results to our application in hl7 message format. Thay told us to use TCP/IP conenction. So I am trying to create a socket to Cobas server. Since they dint the share the port number, we are not able to send the request.

Comment: So how to connect to that server using ip address only

Comment: If you want to connect a url then using http is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Use OS tools on your cobas IT 3000 machine to identify listening ports, e.g., on Linux you could do:

```
netstat --listen
```

but there are many variations -- search for your specific OS. Then construct appropriate HL7 messages to send to the listening port.

Consult the cobas IT 3000 documentation to learn how it consumes HL7 messages, how it's configured, how you can enable debugging, etc. -- your system provider (Roche, VAR, etc.) should be able to provide you this information.